# Is it possible to write a function that applies to every name?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is it possible to provide a function to a object that always gets called when a function is called no matter the name?

Or in other words: Is it possible to have a function, that applies to all possible names?

Maybe with some changes in the object's `prototype`?

Here a example of how this should work:

```
const o = {
  [magic here]: () => 1;
};

o.foo(); // returns 1
o.bar(); // returns 1
o.baz(); // returns 1
```

## Edit for clarification why I want to do this:

I'm experimenting with a railway programming approach. 
Basically instead of checking manually if a object is `null` or `undefined` and reacting accordingly, I want this to be automated.

Example:

```
// checks if object is null and returns a object, that can be called however without crashing
// thanks to T.J. Crowder's answer
function saveNull(o){
  if(o !== null) return o;

  const p = new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      return () => p;
    },
  });

  return p;
}

const a = " abc"; // could be null

const b = a.toUpperCase().trim(); // could crash
const c = a ? a.toUpperCase.trim() : null; // approach 1
const d = a && a.toUpperCase().trim(); // approach 2
const e = saveNull(a).toUpperCase().trim(); // approach 3
```

I find the last approach more readable and interesting to experiment with.

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: I doubt it.....

Comment: Sounds like you want a Proxy but also sounds like you probably need to tell us the [actual problem you are trying to solve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @KristoffDT I added an explanation, on why I want this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in ES2015 and above; you can't do it in ES5 and below.

If you really want every single possible property to return this magic function, then it's fairly simple:

```js
const obj = {};
const magic = () => 1;
const p = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return magic;
  }
});

console.log(p.foo());     // returns 1
console.log(p.bar());     // returns 1
console.log(p.baz());     // returns 1
```

If you want to allow the object to have other properties, and return their values if they're there but the magic function if not, you'd use [`Reflect.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has) to see if the object has the property, and then [`Reflect.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) to get it if so:

```js
const obj = {
  notMagic: 42
};
const magic = () => 1;
const p = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    // If the object actually has the property, return its value
    if (Reflect.has(target, prop)) {
      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    }
    // Return the magic function
    return magic;
  }
});

console.log(p.foo());     // returns 1
console.log(p.bar());     // returns 1
console.log(p.baz());     // returns 1
console.log(p.notMagic);  // 42
```

If you wanted the function to see `this` as the object, you'd use a non-arrow function and probably `bind` to keep things simple:

```js
const obj = {
  notMagic: 42
};
const magic = function() {
  console.log(this === obj);
  return 1;
}.bind(obj);
const p = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    // If the object actually has the property, return its value
    if (Reflect.has(target, prop)) {
      return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
    }
    // Return the magic function
    return magic;
  }
});

console.log(p.foo());     // returns 1
console.log(p.bar());     // returns 1
console.log(p.baz());     // returns 1
console.log(p.notMagic);  // 42
```

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly - Not handling any possible random property name. That was just impossible in ES5, so it can't be polyfilled.